# Please explain why exactly this code finds last array element? How does it work?

Tags: java

For example I have `4` elements in the array:

```
int [] array = new int []{1,2,3,4};  
int last = array[array.length-1];
```

Why does `-1` finds `4` but not `3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays in java are 0-indexed.

- The first element in the array has index 0.
- The second element in the array has index 1.
- The fourth element in the array has index 3.

Hence, to get the final element, you write `arr[arr.length - 1]`. If you try `arr[arr.length]`, you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`: That index is not in the array at all, it's 1 'too large'.

0-indexing has advantages and is more common (in that more programming languages are 0-indexed than 1-indexed). Basic is 1-indexed, I think SQL is more or less 1 indexed, but most other languages (including Java, Python, JavaScript, Scala, Ruby, and C) are all 0-indexed.

Comment: So array has 4 elements, the last one has index 3, so we make array.length(which is 4) -1 and get element with 3rd index(which is number 4), right?

Comment: BASIC is 0-indexed.  At least, BASIC as defined by the people who invented the language.  `DIM X(10)` gets you an 11-element array with subscripts from 0 to 10. You can of course just ignore the 0'th element for most purposes.  See [page 38 in this document](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/dartmouth/BASIC_Oct64.pdf). Particular microcomputer implementations may have got it wrong.

Comment: @Kirill yes, that's right.